# Update Relational table based on another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two table TABLE1 and TABLE2. Now I want to update value in relational table(TABLE2) with matching a ID of Master table(TABLE1) with another table ID and take value from that another table and update into that relational table.

How can i do this?

**TABLE1**

```
ID    
NAME
```

**TABLE2**

```
AUTO_ID 
ID
VALUE
LANGUAGE_ID
```

Now, I have same tables like

**TABLE1_OLD**

```
ID
NAME
```

**TABLE2_OLD**

```
AUTO_ID
ID
VALUE
LANGUAGE_ID
```

So I want to do is, want to take LANGUAGE_ID 2 value from old table and update into new one depend on ID matched.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example with table structures and what exactly you're trying to achieve? It's a bit hard to follow the question, worded as it is.

Comment: Can you explain in detail with table structure?

Comment: updated above. pl check now

Comment: Are you aware that every table in a relational database is a "relational" table? Not sure what you mean with the term "relational table"

Comment: Relational table means have foreign key from master table.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table2 set table2.language_id = your_value_here
WHERE table1.id = table2.id;
```

Comment: table1 is not have language_id field

Comment: what you want from table1?